# I can not migrate tables again

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, migrate, laravel-migrations

I deleted all tables in database, but my error is :

> table.questions exists

so I can not migrate them, does it depend on something else as well?

Comment: empty the database and try `composer dumpautoload` then try to migrate again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it , I had a middleware in boot for question table and added this:

```
   if(\Schema::hasTable('questions')) {
       ....
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can run:**

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

to rollback all the tables (including the migrations table) and recreate everything again.

Comment: @amini.swallow did this answer help you?

Comment: No I answered here it is because of AuthServiceProvider.php . I wrote a middleware .check my answer here please.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible if you really removed all the tables from database.

Make sure you really deleted all tables including `migrations` table.

Normally when you want to revert all migrations you should run:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

If you haven't done this assuming you have are running Laravel 5.5 you can run:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

I would advise you to read the whole [Migrations documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#introduction) to know how they work and how you should create them. In fact you should not remove tables manually and just run:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

to rollback migrations previously run or as I already said you can run one one previously mentioned commands to rollback or rollback and run again your migrations.

Comment: @amini.swallow Are you sure your application is using database you think it's using? Run `php artisan migrate:status` to see what migrations were run, also take a look at `.env` to see database name and run `php artisan config:clear` to make sure no old database connection is cached.

Comment: Yeah , I am sure

Comment: So if you really have clean database it's impossible that you are getting the error. The only chance is when in 2 or more migrations you try to create the same table. Verify if you don't have `Schema::create('questions'` in more than one migration

Comment: I found it,It was because of middleware

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you already have this table in DB. You need to drop a table in `down()` method of each migration and use `php artisan migrate:rollback` command to delete last batch of executed migrations.

In 5.5 you also can use `php artisan migrate:fresh` if you do not drop tables in the `down()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Or you can just manually recreate a DB and run `php artisan migrate` command.

Comment: No I do not have it in database, I also deleted my database and created it again

Answer (score 0):

I've made comments table before and I was making another one for addresses and it said you can't create comments table again!!
I delete comments table and migrate again, both tables made successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).